# 2 different objects one class with Dagger

Tags: android, dagger

I need the module to return 2 different objects Retrofit
how to make the component distinguish between these objects Retrofit ?

Code retrofit

```
@Provides
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Context context, OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("google.com"))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}
```

objects have a difference only in .baseUrl()

Answer (score 0):

For dependencies with same class, you can use `@Named`:

```
@Provides @Named("foo") String provideFoo() {
    return "foo string";
}
```

Inject:

```
public class SomeClass {
    @Inject @Named("foo") String fooString;

    @Inject public SomeClass() {
        System.out.println("value of fooString is " + fooString);
    }
}
```

Your case:

```
@Provides @Named("google")
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Context context, OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("google.com"))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}

@Provides @Named("so")
public Retrofit provideRetrofit(Context context, OkHttpClient okHttpClient, Gson gson) {
    return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .baseUrl("stackoverflow.com"))
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
}
```